# Why don't Response.Write("MasterPage_SaveStateComplete<br/>") launch?

Tags: asp.net

I add a Site.Master file to my ContentPage, I hope to see the order of page launch, 
but I find some codes such as  Response.Write("MasterPage_SaveStateComplete"), Response.Write("MasterPage_PreRenderComplete"); are not launched why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace _01
{
    public partial class ContentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_PreInit<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_Init<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_InitComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_PreLoad<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_Load<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_LoadComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_PreRender<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_PreRenderComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_SaveStateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Page_SaveStateComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write("Page_Unload<br/>");
            int i = 0;
            i++;
        }           

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("Button<br/>");
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace _01
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_PreInit<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_Init<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_InitComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_PreLoad<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_Load<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_LoadComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_PreRender<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_PreRenderComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_SaveStateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("MasterPage_SaveStateComplete<br/>");
        }
        protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write("MasterPage_Unload<br/>");
            int i = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Trace.axd? It'll get you the info you seek without having to do all this.

Comment: Or may be just put trace=true in your page directive. It will give you everything you need (here in context)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the Response.Writes is due to the viewstate not being available at certain points in the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). The viewstate is saved to the page during the Rendering portion of the life cycle.

Unfortunately I never bothered to learn the intricacies of page life cycles so this answer isn't very detailed. Here is a quick [flow chart](http://images.cnblogs.com/cnblogs_com/yandixin/asp.net_page_lifecycle.gif) I found along the way. It shows very clearly what gets called and in what order.